# Migration from postgresql to Mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Hello there i'm really newbie to SQL and i have a problem to create a dump file properly, I have an assignment and i don't really have no idea what's wrong, can anyone help me to migrate it? According to phpmyadmin the error is somewhere in this part.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT (
 DEPTNO              NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,
 DNAME               CHAR(14),
 LOC                 CHAR(13),
 CONSTRAINT DEPT_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO));
```

Comment: Mysql usually (always?) tells what the error exactly is.

Comment: that table looks ok to me, your problem is someplace else. Check [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b7db3/1)

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: 4 errors were found during analysis.
1.A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "CONSTRAINT" at position 158)
 2.Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "EMPNO" at position 198)
   3. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "HIREDATE" at position 208)
4.Unrecognized statement type. (near "DATE" at position 228)

Comment: SQL query:

CREATE TABLE EMP ( EMPNO NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL, ENAME CHAR(10), JOB CHAR(9), MGR NUMERIC(4) CONSTRAINT EMP_SELF_KEY REFERENCES EMP (EMPNO), HIREDATE DATE, SAL NUMERIC(7,2), COMM NUMERIC(7,2), DEPTNO NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT EMP_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO), CONSTRAINT EMP_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO))

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT EMP_SELF_KEY REFERENCES EMP (EMPNO),
HIREDATE            DATE,
SA' at line 5

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an ETL Tool? you dont have to worry about dumps or stuff like that. You just need to know the connection credentials and thats it. I personally use Pentaho ( it's open source ).

1. Download Pentaho ETL from http://kettle.pentaho.org/
2. Unzip and run Pentaho (using .bat file spoon.bat)
3. Create a new Job:

Create DB connection for source data base (PostgreSQL) - using menu: Tools→Wizard→Create DataBase Connection (F3)
Create DB connection for destination data base (Mysql) - using technique described above.

4. Run the Wizard: Tools → Wizard → Copy Tables (Ctrl-F10).
5. Select source (left dialog panel), and destination (left dialog panel). Click Finish.
6. The Job will be generated - Run the job.

Thats it! If you need any help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to open the tools via pgadmin3 but is something like frozen, I reboot my pc and still have no access to the "tools"